# 200 lumens headlamp: Batteries only last a few hours

Tags: headlamps

I have a couple of [Black Diamond Spot Lite 200](https://www.blackdiamondequipment.com/en_US/outlet/spot-lite-200-headlamp/) headlamps. I use [Energizer Max Premium AAA](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B007YASGWS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title) Batteries (Alkaline); using the headlamp on the max setting which emits 200 lumens.

That setup works ok, but I find the batteries only last for about one evening of work (~10 PM to ~2 AM). If I put in new batteries at the start of the evening, the light starts flashing red by the end of the night, indicating the batteries are low.

It's annoying that the headlamp only lasts a few hours in this modern age.

Is there a different headlamp setup I could use to get longer battery life at 200 lumens?

Comment: Batteries only have so much power in them. So, something like the Lightbar can run much longer at ~200 lumens, but it has a much larger battery. So lightweight camping headlamps are not what you should be looking at.

Comment: This Black Diamond [user manual](https://www.manua.ls/black-diamond/spot/manual?p=1) shows a table of lumens output vs burn time. Zooming in shows "300 lumens - 30 hours burn time". Have you tried a different batch of batteries?

Comment: Well, the Spot Lite 200 instructions claim only a 1.5 hour runtime at 200 lumens, so the OP is doing pretty well with whatever batteries they are using.

Comment: Assuming everyone is being honest 200 lumens is going to need about 1-2W. An alkaline AAA is 1000-1200 mAh, and a nominal 2×1.5 V means you have about 3Wh in your batteries.  That gets to around 1.5 hours runtime (as in bob1's answer) up to a maximum of twice that for very efficient LEDs (but in practice the batteries will be too weak by then, hence the reserve mode to get the most out of them).  So either you're not using it constantly all shift, or you're not using it on that setting (or some combination).

Comment: @ChrisH Yeah, I must be turning it off more often than I remembered.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Noah's answer, the Black Diamond Spot 200, as linked in your answer, has [a manual](https://blackdiamond-web.cdn.prismic.io/blackdiamond-web/65b53815-93f5-4e59-b814-66816c90a045_M14145_B_SpotLite-200_IS-WEB.pdf) (PDF) with an estimated run time for output intensity. The table is in the top-left of the manual, but I have reproduced it here (Image copyright: © Black Diamond Equipment, Ltd. 2020):

[image: runtime, distance vs output]

This table indicates that if you don't run the headlamp at full power, and instead run it at the 100 lm setting, you should get 12 hours of runtime, versus the 1.5 hours of full brightness you get with the 200 lm setting. However, there is a caveat here; the asterisk next to runtime indicates runtime to 10% of the initial setting - so the lamp will be getting dim at this point. The reserve is running at 0.25 lux as measured at 4 metres/~13 feet; which is bright enough for walking, but not much more (though if the 4 m is a radius, then this is still 50 lm according to an on-line calculator).

I have this very headlamp, and can tell you that the medium 100 lm setting is definitely bright enough for almost all the things one might want to do. This setting has either the spotlight or the wide beam lit-up, but not both.

Comment: If you really want a headlamp with hundreds of lumens and long runtime, some of the mountain biking ones can be written without a helmet, and have a rechargeable battery pack to be worn lower down. You'd want to check the minimum output on those as they often reach over 1000 lumens into a fairly wide cone

Comment: so, that's just a case of rtfm, then

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to last longer you need a larger battery. Some headlamps might be a touch more efficient, but ultimately the size of the battery will be what affects battery life the most. If you want a compact headlamp like the black diamond you can't really do that much better. Larger battery models, such as [Moonlight's Bright As Day](https://moonlightmountaingear.com/collections/lighting/products/bright-as-day-800-headlamp), exist, which offers a quoted 8hrs at 200lm. As Jon points out in his comment, you might be better off looking at something other than a headlamp.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to buy a new light

buy a rechargeable one.  You get better runtime for the weight, and charging is cheap compared to buying batteries.  The [Petzl Swift](https://brightguy.com/product/petzl-swift-rl-usb-rechargeable-headlamp/) looks suitable, if pricey.

### Otherwise, using your existing light

I've adapted (AA) head torches to run off *rechargeable lithium batteries*.  They hold about 4× as much power - about twice the mAh (current × time) but a bit just over twice the voltage.

Because they're twice the voltage, you have to only use 1 instead of 2 in series.  There are dummy batteries which allow you to make the modification temporarily.  I rewired my battery boxes instead.

Lithium rechargeable batteries need a special charger, not the same one as NiMh.

### There are also a few other options, using the same light

Note that 1.5V rechargeable lithium AAAs are sold, but I've never used them and can't find enough technical information on charging to recommend them.

NiMh rechargeable batteries would save you money, but you'd probably have to swap a fresh set in mid-shift.  They're nominally 1.2V each but I'd expect the LED driver in this lamp to cope. Probably.

There are also Lithium primary (non-rechargeable) batteries, with 1.5V output.  They would end up costing more, for the convenience of not having to swap so often.